# Puppet: deploy certificate from active node to stand-by node

Tags: puppet

I'm working on a Puppet module which configures UCARP, HAProxy using [Puppet Lab's haproxy module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/haproxy) and generates X.509 using the Let's Encrypt CA via [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). I managed to write the Puppet code in a way to configure HAProxy and setup the Let's Encrypt certificates in a single Puppet run:

1. Configure HAProxy with a single HTTP listener, redirecting requests to the URI `/.well-known/acme-challenge` to a high-port on the local system.
2. Start HAProxy.
3. Retrieve certificates using `certbot` via Let's Encrypt's staging servers by listening on the mentioned high-port on the local system. If it fails, abort.
4. Delete the staging certificates.
5. Retrieve certificates using `certbot` via Let's Encrypt's live servers. If it fails abort.
6. Add HTTPS listeners to HAProxy's configuration using the Let's Encrypt certificates.
7. Reload HAProxy.

These steps work as expected.

Via a custom Puppet fact, Puppet knows which system is the active one and which systems are stand-by nodes. So the certificates will be generated and renewed on the node which is active.

Now my question is, how can I deploy the generated certificates on the other stand-by nodes? I looked into [exported resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_exported.html), but I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to due it.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: I would try to solve it using https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/minionfs.html :-)

Comment: I thought about doing something similar, but to me this does not seem the correct way to do it - too much overhead.